# Обновление JTable после обновления БД

Tags: java, swing, jtable

У меня есть БД с таблицей зарегистрированных пользователей (с балансом) и таблицей депозитов (пополнение счета). На фрейме есть JTable, которая отображает депозиты, и кнопка добавления депозитов. Нажал, ввел id пользователя и X сумму, после чего баланс заполняется на X. Проблема в том, что новый депозит не отображается в таблице депозитов, то есть JTable не меняется, пока я не перезагружу программу. Попробовал методы `updateUI()`, `fireTableDataChanged()`, `revalidate()`, `repaint()`, но саму таблицу они на вид не меняют. Как мне быть?

Код нажатия кнопки:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO deposits VALUES(NULL,"
                                + Integer.parseInt(newDepositUserIDTextField
                                        .getText())
                                + ","
                                + Integer.parseInt(newDepositSumTextField
                                        .getText()) + ",'" + time + "')");
                        depositsTableMode.fireTableDataChanged();
                        depositsTable.updateUI();
                        depositsTable.repaint();
```

Код моделя таблицы:

```
public class DepositsTableMode extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3918779794437245084L;
    private String[] depositsTableHeader = { "ID", "User ID", "Sum", "Date" };
    private ArrayList<Object[]> depositsTableData = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    public DepositsTableMode() {
        ArrayList<Object[]> depositsTableData = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < depositsTableData.size(); i++)
            depositsTableData.add(new Object[4]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return depositsTableData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Object[] row = depositsTableData.get(rowIndex);
        return row[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (depositsTableData.isEmpty()) {
            return Object.class;
        }
        return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            if (i == columnIndex)
                return depositsTableHeader[i];
        return "";
    }

    public void addDeposit(Object[] deposit) {
        Object[] deposit0 = new Object[4];
        deposit0 = deposit;
        depositsTableData.add(deposit0);
    }
```

Код создания таблицы:

```
DepositsTableMode depositsTableMode = new DepositsTableMode();
        JTable depositsTable = new JTable(depositsTableMode);
        try {
            Object[] deposit = null;
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM deposits");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                deposit = new Object[4];
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    deposit[i] = resultSet.getObject(i + 1);
                depositsTableMode.addDeposit(deposit);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Сама картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

создайте отдельный метод, который будет заполнять таблицу(брать данные из БД и вносить их в таблицу), вызовите его при старте GUI.

Далее на кнопке оставляете запрос и после него вызываете перерисовку таблицы.

Таким образом таблица у вас всегда будет заполняться актуальными данными.

---

Посоветовал бы вам создать отдельный класс описывающий ваш элемент таблицы

```
public class User{
    private int id;
    private int userId;
    private int summ;
    private Date date;
```

добавить геттеры\сеттеры и им оперировать, а не Object

вынести

```
    try {
        Object[] deposit = null;
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM deposits");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            deposit = new Object[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                deposit[i] = resultSet.getObject(i + 1);
            depositsTableMode.addDeposit(deposit);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

в отдельный метод, который будет заполнять список List и возвращать его.

По нажатию на кнопку выполнять запрос вставки с БД, потом вызвать метод и получить список свежих User и ими отредактировать таблицу

Answer (score 0):

Не обновляется, потому что вставляете в базу данных, а не в модель таблицы. То есть базу обновляете, а таблицу нет.
Вообще то, как по мне, модель таблицы немного корявая. Проще в качестве данных задать экземпляр ResultSet, который передавать в конструкторе, и с ним уже работать. При изменении данных меняете их только с помощью ResultSet, таблица будет меняться сама.